# Should I use one XML Parser for every XML feed I have, or should I write a parser for each XML feed I have?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

So I help write an app for my university and I'm wondering what's the best way to handle multiple XML feeds (like scores for sports, class information, etc.).

Should I have one XML parser that can handle all feeds? Or should I write a parser for each feed? We're having trouble deciding the best way to implement it.

This is iOS and we use a mix of Swift 3 and Objective-C

Comment: The term "parser" is often used incorrectly and usually we understand what is meant. But here I'm not sure what you mean. An XML parser knows nothing about the specific vocabulary, it just looks for start and end tags, and you should definitely be using an off-the-shelf XML parser rather than writing your own. I think you're talking about the application that invokes the XML parser, not about the parser itself, and in that case the answer to your question is: it depends whether there are sufficient areas of commonality between the different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right strategy is to write a base class that handles common data types like integers, booleans, strings, etc., and then write derived classes for each type of feed. This is the strategy I use in my XML parser, which is based on the data structures and Apple's XML parser as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html

Personally I prefer to use the XPath data models where you can query the XML tree for a specific node using a path-like string.